# What is file table, environment segment in c object code?

Tags: c, dos

"When we execute our C program, operating system loads the program into memory. In case of DOS, it first loads 256 bytes into memory, called program segment prefix. This contains file table, environment segment, and command line information" - I read this in a documentation of C language. 
My question is that what is **file table, environment segment**?

Comment: Perhaps this mysterious "documentation of C language" that you're keeping from us all goes on to explore these terms in greater detail...?

Comment: @Dayalrai: That's the Windows Installer documentation. It has nothing at all to do with the DOS Program Segment Prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a whole article on the [Program Segment Prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix), with links to detail on the features that it contains.

From it, we may deduce that:

- the **[file table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_File_Table)** is where open file handles live; and
- the **[environment segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)** contains the names and values for all *environment variables* in scope.